# almost planar graphs are minor closed

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory, graph-minors

I'm trying to show that [almost planar graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPlanarGraph.html) are minor-closed. For that I need to show if $G-e$ is planar, then $G/e$ is almost planar (and vice versa).

My approach: I'm trying to show this using the fact that a planar graph has no $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor. So all I know is that if $G/e$ does have one of those as a minor, then the vertex to which $e$ has been contracted to, would be part of the minor (otherwise $G-e$ would also have them as a minor). I'm not sure how to go forward from here.

Comment: Which definition of almost planar graphs are you using? Your link has two...

Comment: Gubser's definition: either $G-e$ or $G/e$ is planar

Comment: In that case, can you convince yourself of the following: If $H$ is a minor of $G$ and $e$ is an edge of $H$, then there exists an edge $e'$ of $G$ such that $H-e$ is a minor of $G-e'$, and $H/e$ is a minor of $G/e'$? From there, the minor-closed nature of almost planar graphs follows almost immediately.

Comment: What is the quantifier on $e$?  But also in general it is much easier to show that something is minor-closed than to find its collection of minimal excluded minors.

Comment: @JBL Looking at other sources, it seems a graph is almost planar when, for every edge $e$, at least one of $G-e$ or $G/e$ is planar.

Comment: Apologies, some mistakes in my answer. Will give it another go later tonight.

Comment: The original paper "A Characterization of Almost-Planar Graphs" by Gubser gives some results that easily imply what you are looking for (although they are somewhat overkill).